# Failed to send email with Play Framework 1.2.5

Tags: java, email, playframework

I would like send e-mail with play farmework. I configure my application.conf

```
# Testing. Set up a custom configuration for test mode
# ~~~~~
#%test.module.cobertura=${play.path}/modules/cobertura
%test.application.mode=dev
%test.db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
%test.jpa.ddl=create
%test.mail.smtp=mock

#Testing use smtp gmail
#~~~~~~~
mail.debug=true
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.user=mymail@gmail.com
mail.smtp.pass=mypassword
mail.smtp.channel=ssl
```

I create a new template email in /views/Mails/welcome.html  and welcome.txt
And i write static method will be an e-mail sender

```
package notifiers;

import play.*;
import play.libs.Mail;
import play.mvc.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.mail.Folder;

public class Mails extends Mailer {

    public static void welcome(){
        setSubject("Test Send Mail");
        addRecipient("target@gmail.com");
        setFrom("Me <me@me.com>");
        send();
    }
}
```

I have in my output console message

```
begin function welcom()
10:30:36,857 INFO  ~ From Mock Mailer


New email received by   
        From: me@me.com     
        ReplyTo: me@me.com  
        To: "target@gmail.com" <target@gmail.com>
        Subject: Test Send Mail

        text/plain; charset=UTF-8: hello world

        text/html; charset=UTF-8: <html>
        <body>
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </body>
        </html> 


finish function welcom()
```

finally I do not receive mail.
Pls help.Thank you.

Comment: Any error message? Are you sure your `welcome()` method was executed?

Comment: Yes. I insert two System.out.println() in welcome(), and mail.debug in  application.conf works.
**output console message** `begin function welcom()

09:41:50,499 INFO  ~ From Mock Mailer
 New email received by
 From: vincnet.iam@gmail.com
 ReplyTo: vincnet.iam@gmail.com
 To: "vincnet.iam@gmail.com" <vincnet.iam@gmail.com>
 Subject: Test Send Mail
 text/plain; charset=UTF-8: hello world 
 text/html; charset=UTF-8: <html>
 <body>
  <p>Hello world</p>
 </body>
</html> 
 

finish function welcom()`

Comment: You should better edit the question to include the logs instead of posting it all in the comments. It's way easier to read. :) Anyway, `From Mock Mailer` indicates that you're not really sending email. Do you have a `mail.smtp=mock` in your configuration somewhere?

Comment: Yes mail.smtp=mock is commented ? It's regular ?

Comment: Yes, it should be commented out. If it isn't, then please do so. Play's default behaviour is to have the mock mailer in DEV mode and whatever you configure in PROD mode.

Comment: `%test.mail.smtp=mock` it isn't commented. I add more informations in my first post on application.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the line

```
mail.smtp=mock
```

somewhere in your `application.conf`. This makes Play use a mock mailer instead of mailing via an SMTP server. The default behaviour is to have the mock mailer in DEV mode and an SMTP mailer in PROD mode. You can change this behaviour by commenting out the mentioned line in your config.

Also please note that you shouldn't be using Play 1.2.5 anymore. The currently newest version of the 1.X  branch is 1.2.7. Your version, 1.2.5, contains a [session injection vulnerability](http://www.playframework.com/security/vulnerability/20130806-SessionInjection).